# installing application published in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

i built a very simple application in vb.net, installed it, it worked. then i did some very slight updates, build it, tried to install it but got the following errors. i restarted computer, uninstalled app for the uninstall menu, and tried to run setup.exe and still have been getting this error. can someone help!

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 5.1.2600.196608 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 2.0.50727.3053
    System.Deployment.dll       : 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    mscorwks.dll            : 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    dfdll.dll           : 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    dfshim.dll          : 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/PGarcia.BMRA/Desktop/Intol%20Prog/WindowsApplication1.application

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : WindowsApplication1.application, Version=1.0.0.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9ac82ee8eb508b4, processorArchitecture=msil

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Documents and Settings\PGarcia.BMRA\Desktop\Intol Prog\WindowsApplication1.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading file:///C:/Documents and Settings/PGarcia.BMRA/Desktop/Intol Prog/Application Files/WindowsApplication1_1_0_0_4/WindowsApplication1.exe.manifest did not succeed.
        + Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Documents and Settings\PGarcia.BMRA\Desktop\Intol Prog\Application Files\WindowsApplication1_1_0_0_4\WindowsApplication1.exe.manifest'.
        + Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Documents and Settings\PGarcia.BMRA\Desktop\Intol Prog\Application Files\WindowsApplication1_1_0_0_4\WindowsApplication1.exe.manifest'.
        + Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Documents and Settings\PGarcia.BMRA\Desktop\Intol Prog\Application Files\WindowsApplication1_1_0_0_4\WindowsApplication1.exe.manifest'.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [6/9/2009 12:07:19 PM] : Activation of C:\Documents and Settings\PGarcia.BMRA\Desktop\Intol Prog\WindowsApplication1.application has started.
    * [6/9/2009 12:07:19 PM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [6/9/2009 12:07:19 PM] : Installation of the application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [6/9/2009 12:07:19 PM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading file:///C:/Documents and Settings/PGarcia.BMRA/Desktop/Intol Prog/Application Files/WindowsApplication1_1_0_0_4/WindowsApplication1.exe.manifest did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifest(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ManifestType manifestType, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Documents and Settings\PGarcia.BMRA\Desktop\Intol Prog\Application Files\WindowsApplication1_1_0_0_4\WindowsApplication1.exe.manifest'.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Documents and Settings\PGarcia.BMRA\Desktop\Intol Prog\Application Files\WindowsApplication1_1_0_0_4\WindowsApplication1.exe.manifest'.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
        - Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Documents and Settings\PGarcia.BMRA\Desktop\Intol Prog\Application Files\WindowsApplication1_1_0_0_4\WindowsApplication1.exe.manifest'.
        - Source: mscorlib
        - Stack trace:
            at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
            at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
            at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
            at System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length, Boolean async)
            at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Comment: Does the path "'C:\Documents and Settings\PGarcia.BMRA\Desktop\Intol Prog\Application Files\WindowsApplication1_1_0_0_4" exist on the machine you are deploying to?  What is in the directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Command promt and run this...

For 32 Bit Machine

C:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ aspnet_regiis.exe -i

For 64 Bit Machine

C:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\ aspnet_regiis.exe -i

Answer (score 1):

looks to be missing a file .manifest? or possibly a file/folder that got moved since last build.

if you are using source control try rolling back and looking for a missing file/files.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a ClickOnce application, which you did not specify but I'm deducing from the error report, you may have one of several issues. When you publish a ClickOnce application you must be certain that your version number is incremented from the last released/installed version or ClickOnce will get confused.

Also, be sure you deploy *all* of your published files to the deployment server, including your new manifest file. ClickOnce does a hash on the files to ensure they have not been tampered with.

My apologies if this is not a ClickOnce-deployed application.